# This script acts for all players, how do I make it act for only one player?

Tags: lua, roblox

I have this script, and when I run it, it works, but, on all players and I only want it to be for the one who touched it.

Code:

```
local CooldownTime = 0.15
local Debounce = false

game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(plr)
    script.Parent.Touched:Connect(function()
    if Debounce == false then
        Debounce = true
        if plr.leaderstats.Cash.Value >= 125 then
            if plr.leaderstats.EnhancerMulti.Value <= 2 then
                plr.leaderstats.Multiplier.Value = plr.leaderstats.Multiplier.Value +1
            else
                plr.leaderstats.Multiplier.Value = plr.leaderstats.Multiplier.Value + (plr.leaderstats.EnhancerMulti.Value)
            end
            plr.leaderstats.Cash.Value = plr.leaderstats.Cash.Value == 0
            wait(CooldownTime)
            Debounce = false
        else 
            Debounce = false
        end
    end
    end)
end)
```

I tried this, and I expected it to work on only one player, not all of them.

Answer (score 0):

For every player who joins you add a callback to the part, which executes the code for that player.

Imagine 2 players join. You then have 2 callbacks. Player 1 now touches the object, and the object triggers all the 2 callbacks, thus for both players.

Instead of adding a callback per player, add a single one and use the touched part (first and only argument) to determine the player: https://create.roblox.com/docs/reference/engine/classes/BasePart#Touched

When player 1 now touches the object, the only callback triggers and provides you with the player.

Read the doc regarding collisions: https://create.roblox.com/docs/building-and-visuals/physics/detecting-collisions

Here is a forum entry discussing Player specific collisions: https://devforum.roblox.com/t/how-to-get-player-from-touched-event/260923

Comment: Could you show how to do this? This is kinda confusing for me.

Comment: Also, if I do it with touched(to my knowledge), it goes to my character, not my player which is what I need.

Comment: I extended the answer with helpful links. Since you can retrieve a Player from a Character it is not much different. (`Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(touched.Parent)`)